# PowerShell If Else Statement Based on Function Output

Tags: powershell, automation

I need to be connected to a VPN connection in order to access an internal website. The VPN software does not have any mechanism for automatically connecting so I am looking to automate it using PowerShell.
My PowerShell skills are very basic and I need help getting my script working. I have taken bits and pieces of code from the web and it works when I launch each function as a separate script but when I try an If Else statement to check the VPN status it seems to launch the functions in the wrong sequence.

I have made  separate functions for each task in my script.

1. VPN-Check: Check if website is accessible. If HTTP response is OK return true. If inaccessible return false.
2. VPN-Connect: Launch the VPN client software and then send keypresses to simulate entering in the password and clicking connect.
3. VPN-Disconnect: Simulate hitting disconnect on the VPN software and stop the VPN services.
4. VPN-Cleanup: Kills any remaining VPN processes and services

After defining all my functions this is my code:

```
function VPN-Check {
# First we create the request.
$HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('https://portal.domain.com/portal/login.jsp')

# We then get a response from the site.
$HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()

# We then get the HTTP code as an integer.
$HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode

If ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) {
#Write-Host "Site is OK!"
return $true
}
Else {
#Write-Host "The Site may be down, please check!"
return $false
}

# Finally, we clean up the http request by closing it.
If ($HTTP_Response -eq $null) { } 
Else { $HTTP_Response.Close() }
}

function VPN-Connect {
write-host "Connecting to the VPN..."
Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\AT&T Global Network Client\NetClient.exe"
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('AT&T Global Network Client')
Sleep 10
#$wshell.SendKeys('~')
#sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('{TAB}')
sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('{TAB}')
sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('{TAB}')
sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('{TAB}')
sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('{TAB}')
sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('{TAB}')
sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('MyPassw0rd')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('~')
}

function VPN-Disconnect {
write-host "Disconnecting from VPN..."
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('AT&T Global Network Client')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('~')
sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('{TAB}')
sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('~')
sleep 1
taskkill /im "NetClient.exe"
net stop "AT&T Network Configuration Service"
net stop "AT&T Global Network Client Service"
}

function VPN-Cleanup {
write-host "Killing the VPN..."
taskkill /f /im "NetClient.exe"
net stop "AT&T Network Configuration Service"
net stop "AT&T Global Network Client Service"
}

$Isconnected = VPN-Check
If ($Isconnected = "False") {
write-host "Connecting to VPN..."
VPN-Cleanup
VPN-Connect
}
else ($Isconnected = "True") {write-host "Already connected. Nothing to do"}
```

Comment: `=` is the _assignment_ operator - it doesn't make comparisons :) you want `if(-not $Isconnected){ <# cleanup and connect#> }else{ <# already connected #>}`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the two last lines in function `VPN-Check` and add

```
if ($HTTP_Response) {$HTTP_Response.Close()}
```

Immediately **above** the if..else where you test the `$HTTP_Status`

Then change `If ($Isconnected = "False") {..} else ...` into

```
If (-not $Isconnected) {
    write-host "Connecting to VPN..."
    VPN-Cleanup
    VPN-Connect
}
else {
    write-host "Already connected. Nothing to do"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work. Issue is now if the site is completely unreachable I get this exception: Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The operation has timed out" how do I not cause an exception if there is a timeout?

Comment: @ChauncyPeppertooth Wrap that call inside a `try{..} catch {..}`